# When do you need Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm a bit confused concerning the usage of the different "**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*"** NuGet packages. 
When you have a look at the official MS documentation (which can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/ef/core/get-started/install/)

They always talk about installation of a specific package, e.g. **"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"**, never about installing the main core package **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**.

In my opinion, if you do not want the add any specific dataprovider, you only install "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCode" and next load a specific dataprovider from configuration. For example if you want both support for SQLServer and Oracle. Is this the way i should see it, or is there any other reason(s) ?

Thx for any response.

Emmanuel Nuyttens

Comment: In order to configure a concrete provider, you must do that in code, and that piece of code requires the concrete provider